# Check if my time series is forecastable using Shannon entropy

Tags: time-series, entropy, forecastability

According to this answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/95232/141037, is possible to verify the forecastability of a time series using the Shannon entropy, the lower the Shannon entropy value, the more forecastable it is. My question is: the time series I use for forecasting tests (regression problem) is windowed (shape (videos, frames, frame height, frame width), I applied a sliding window to it). Can I use this windowed time series to calculate shannon entropy?

Comment: Sure you can. What are you going to do with that entropy? Entropy here is a statistic that is derived from your data. What you need to understand is what values of this statistic are important for you, and whether this statistic is sensitive enough to things you care about. My advice would be to generate some synthetic data which is either completely noise, or time-correlated. Process that data as you wish (windowing etc), calculate entropy, and then decide whether the obtained signal is useful

Comment: For example, you calculate entropy and you get 42.0.... now what?

Comment: @Cryo I'm thinking about analyzing different sections of my windowed time series to see which are the most forecastable, so that I can then test these most forecastable parts via machine learning. Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. It feels to me like you will still need to know what meaningful difference in entropy is. So it might be a good idea to simulate what you are planning to do, to understand what entropies to expect

Comment: This will answer your 'can I' question as well

Comment: Cool. What do you mean by to simulate what I'm planning to do, to understand what entropies to expect?

Comment: It is the case in many applied predictive situations that 'ground truth' for the model either isn't available or, more simply, does not exist. In such cases model validation is obtained from the usefulness of the results: does it predict? are greater (lesser) values of a metric helpful or insightful? And so on. Wrt time series information theoretic metrics such as *permutation entropy* may be more useful than Shannon entropy. See Brandmaier's papers on PE https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i05

Answer (score 0):

You can apply any technique you want to your data, the trouble will always be with interpreting the results. Say you compute entropy, how do you know which entropy is significant? How do you know one signal's entropy is substantially larger/smaller than another?

Besides analytical derivations, here one can take an empirical approach. What type of time-series are you expecting to forecast? Say something similar to ARMA with one independent variable:

$$
\begin{align}
y_t-\phi \cdot y_{t-1}&=\epsilon_t-\theta \cdot \epsilon_{t-1} + \eta\cdot x_t \\
\left(\begin{array} \\ 
1 & -\phi & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -\phi & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \dots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \dots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 &-\phi & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \dots & 1 & -\phi\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 &1 \\
\end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array} \\ 
y_t \\
y_{t-1} \\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
y_2
\\
y_1
\end{array} \right)&=
\left(\begin{array} \\ 
\epsilon_t-\theta\cdot \epsilon_{t-1}+\eta\cdot x_t \\
\epsilon_{t-1}-\theta\cdot \epsilon_{t-2}+\eta\cdot x_{t-1} \\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\epsilon_2-\theta\cdot y_1+\eta\cdot x_2
\\
\epsilon_1+\eta\cdot x_1
\end{array} \right) 
\end{align}
$$

Where $\epsilon_{\dots}$ is your noise, $x_{\dots}$ is the independent variable, $y_{\dots}$ is dependent (and is zero for $t\le 0$). One can re-arrange the above to:

$$
\left(\begin{array} \\ 
y_t \\
y_{t-1} \\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
y_2
\\
y_1
\end{array} \right)=
\left(\begin{array} \\ 
1 & \phi & \phi^2 & \phi^3 & \dots & \phi^{n-1} & \phi^{n-2} & \phi^{n-1}\\
0 & 1 & \phi & \phi^2 & \phi^3 & \dots & \phi^{n-1} & \phi^{n-2} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 &\phi & \phi^2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \dots & 1 & \phi\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 &1 \\
\end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array} \\ 
\epsilon_t-\theta\cdot \epsilon_{t-1}+\eta\cdot x_t \\
\epsilon_{t-1}-\theta\cdot \epsilon_{t-2}+\eta\cdot x_{t-1} \\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\epsilon_2-\theta\cdot y_1+\eta\cdot x_2
\\
\epsilon_1+\eta\cdot x_1
\end{array} \right) 
$$

Where we assume $n$ time-steps. So all you need to do now is generate random $\epsilon$, choose $\theta,\phi$ and $x_t$. Then plug everything into the vector on the right, multiply it by the matrix (formally the inverse of a Lag Operator matrix). And you will get time-series that is correlated as per your spec. You can then apply all the procedures you want on it, and test to see whether those procedures will allow you to distinguish between predictable (mostly controlled by large $\eta$ and $\phi$) and un-predictable time-series. You can even get an empirical distribution of your entropy (by repeating this process many times.)

This is just one example of course. There are other ways you can generate time series. This one is nice because it is analytically tractable

Comment: Quick link on the inverse of a Lag operator, in case it helps https://ealdrich.github.io/Teaching/Econ211C/LectureNotes/Unit1-ARMA/lagOperators.html#inverse-of-lag-operator